# Expanding header with browser

Tags: html, css, text, header

I have a header in a website that I want to fill the top portion of the site no matter what the browser size is.

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Holtwood One SC';
    color: #1C003A;
    font-size: 4em;
}
#header {   
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

<div id="header"><a href="index.html"><h1>Spilling the Beans</h1></a></div>
```

this is the CSS and HTML. The div for the header is just in the body. I don't know what to input to make this expand and shrink with the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you just remove the `float:left` and `width:95%`, then it will automatically take the full width of the browser because that's the default.

If, however, you're actually talking about making the text size itself get bigger and smaller depending on browser size, you can try using Viewport Units:

```
h1 {
    font-size:4em;
    font-size:5vw;
}
```

It is very important to have the first one be in `pt`, `px`, `em` or other common unit, so that browsers that don't support Viewport Units have something to fall back on. As for the Viewport Unit, adjust as desired. You can also use `vh` instead of `vw` to adjust the text size based on the height of the viewport rather than the width.

If this isn't what you mean either, please be more specific.

Comment: thank you, i do want the text itself to increase or decrease in font size, but the viewport units didn't seem to work.

Comment: Viewport units are only supported in a [very limited set of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) because it's so new in the specifications.

Comment: i'm using google chrome. it's the latest version, and i checked compatibility. i don't understand what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Right-click the header and choose Inspect Element. In the window (or panel) that appears, look for the styles. All being well, you should see `font-size:4em` crossed out, and `font-size:5vw` there and working.

Comment: ohhh i see you have to refresh the window. not exactly what i was looking for, but that should suffice. thank you!

Comment: Erm... Viewport units should update automatically when you resize the browser window, that's kind of the point of them. If it's not... well I guess that may be a bug in Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

you should be setting your margins in `body` and remove `float` and `margin` on the header

```
body{
    margin:0; padding:20px;
}
#header {   
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:auto;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/8dtqs/